# can't get this divider class

Tags: java, string, user-input

I'm using Helsinki's Java course and I can't seem to get the proper code even though it outputs the right answer.
Here's the prompt:
Create a program that asks the user for two integers and prints their quotient. Make sure that 3 / 2 = 1.5. If the decimal part is missing, take another look at 6.1 Floating point numbers (decimal numbers) to find the solution.

Type a number: 3
Type another number: 2

Division: 3 / 2 = 1.5

And here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Divider {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type a number:");
        double X = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Type another number:");
        double Y = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        double Z =  X/Y;
        System.out.println("Division:" + Z);
        // Implement your program here. Remember to ask the input from user.
    }
}
```

This is the error message that I get:
FAIL: DividerTest testDivider
Your output should be of the form 'X / Y = Z' for some integers X, Y and Z. Now it was: 1.5

Can anyone suggest how I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: What's your question? What should be the desired output?

Comment: This is working well. what is your problem?

Comment: I have no idea, this is on Helsinki's Java course and it marks it wrong even though it does division right.

Comment: As this code compiles and runs fine, it seems to me like your code is validated automatically by some educational system and an output in a certain format is expected. E.g. use System.out.printf("%f / %f = %f\n", X, Y, Z), rather than the call to println.

Comment: Yes these automated validations are sometimes really annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simply that your last System.out.println statement gives the output in the wrong format (as it says in the error message: "Your output should be of the form 'X / Y = Z")

Try changing the output to

```
System.out.println(X + " / " + Y + " = " + Z);
```